# How can i make the first option of select element run after the page renders in react for the first time?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, drop-down-menu

I have a select element in react with some options and i want the first option or the "selected" option to execute the value on screen when page is rendered initially. React for some reason doesn't do it. My code is below

```
<p>{selectState}</p>
          <Select
            id="mySelect"
            value={selectState}
            onChange={(e) => setSelectState(e.target.value)}
          >
            <Option value="red" selected>Red</Option>
            <Option value="black">Black</Option>
            <Option value="blue">Blue</Option>
            <Option value="yellow">Yellow</Option>
          </Select>
          <Select>
```

the first

element shows me selected values but i want to see red being printed when the page loads for the first time, please tell me how i can do it.[This is what i see when page loads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceLCW.png)[This is what i want to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M05OI.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want an initial value of `red` for `selectState` on first load. You can achieve this by adding the `red` value in the [`useState`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState) hook as follows:

```
const [selectState, setSelectState] = useState("red");

<Select
  id="mySelect"
  value={selectState}
  onChange={(e) => setSelectState(e.target.value)}
>
  <Option value="red">
    Red
  </Option>
  <Option value="black">Black</Option>
  <Option value="blue">Blue</Option>
  <Option value="yellow">Yellow</Option>
</Select>
```

Comment: oh my god u solved it, thank u so much dude

Comment: @muzammil No problems. Could you please upvote my answer and accept it as the correct answer? It will help others you come across this question :)

Comment: i would love to but i dont have enough reputations to cast a vote yet, i will do in the future :-)